# How to invoke/reference Map/dictionaries before its initalized in dart?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, dictionary, variables

```
account(initial_balance) {
  deposit(amount) {
    dispatch['balance'] += amount; //error message on dispatch here.
    return dispatch['balance'];//error message on dispatch here.
  }

  withdraw(amount) {
    if (amount > dispatch['balance']) { //error message on dispatch here.
      return 'Insufficient funds';
    }
    dispatch['balance'] -= amount;//error message on dispatch here.
    return dispatch['balance'];//error message on dispatch here.
  }

  var dispatch = {
    'deposit': deposit,
    'withdraw': withdraw,
    'balance': initial_balance
  };
  return dispatch;
}

withdraw(account, amount) {
  return account['withdraw'](amount);
}

deposit(account, amount) {
  return account['deposit'](amount);
}

check_balance(account) {
  return account['balance'];
}
```

I translated this code from python dictionaries, But in dart i am getting the following error

> "Local variable dispatch cannot be referenced before it is
> declared.Try renaming/moving the declaration before first use so that
> it doesn't hide a name from enclosing scope"

Any ideas on what is causing this type of error and how i can use dictionary without having to declare it before the functions? The code works in python where i can declare dictionary in the last part of the function.

Comment: @jamesdlin Oh wow that works! I added an empty dispatch map like you said and that solved the issue. += adds the amount to the balance. Can you please convert your comment to a answer i will pick it as best answer in case if someone else runs into similar error message in future.

Comment: @jamesdlin is your concern about `dispatch['balance']` caused by `initial_balance` being `dynamic`? because when passing an `int` or `double`, the above code works. After applying your fix of course.
On that note I would suggest changing `account` signature to `account(num initial_balance)`.

Comment: @MohamedMohsin Ah, I got confused by the `dispatch` having heterogeneous values.  I incorrectly thought that all of the values were meant to be functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `dispatch` must be declared before it is referenced.  You can declare `dispatch` separately (either as an empty `Map` or as a `late` variable) before defining the local functions, and you then can add those references later.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> account(dynamic initial_balance) {
  late Map<String, dynamic> dispatch;
  
  dynamic deposit(dynamic amount) {
    dispatch['balance'] += amount;
    return dispatch['balance'];
  }

  dynamic withdraw(dynamic amount) {
    if (amount > dispatch['balance']) {
      return 'Insufficient funds';
    }
    dispatch['balance'] -= amount;
    return dispatch['balance'];
  }

  dispatch = <String, dynamic>{
    'deposit': deposit,
    'withdraw': withdraw,
    'balance': initial_balance
  };
  return dispatch;
}
```